# how to edit form field in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to use mat-input, mat-autocomplete and mat-select all at the same time at once just like the design below but I'm not really sure how to implement all of them to work so it will really awesome if someone can give me suggestion or help me out. I want the user to be able to enter text and automatically show existing similar text if there is one in the list and also user can view all the list immediately by clicking down icon on the right side.

```
    <mat-form-field class="demo-chip-list" appearance="fill">
        <mat-chip-list #chipList>
            <mat-chip  *ngFor="let chip of chips" [selectable]="selectable" [removable]="removable" (removed)="removeTags(chip)">
                {{chip.tag}}
            </mat-chip>

            <input matInput  #input [(ngModel)]="tagIn" placeholder="Select or Create a tag" [formControl]="tagCtrl2" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [matChipInputFor]="chipList" />
        </mat-chip-list>

        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let tag of filteredTags | async" [value]="tag">
                {{tag}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
```

I'm trying to do like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found something inside the Angular Material documentation:

https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples

Go down to "Option groups autocomplete", Thats a pretty nice way of showing the list and allowing the user to type what he wants.

Comment: oh.. thanks but I just noticed that that is what I have right now and I didn't eve realized it.. lol by anychance do you know how I can add down arrow icon on the side. do you if there is possible way to do that?

Comment: Yes, you can use a matSuffix inside your mat-form-field, here is an example, check the first example in this link and see how the "x" is beeing included.
https://material.angular.io/components/input/examples

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

```
    <mat-form-field>
        <label for="tagInput">Select or Create a tag</label>
            <input matInput [formControl]="tagCtrl2" [matAutocomplete]="auto"/>
            <mat-autocomplete id="tagInput" #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
                <mat-option *ngFor="tag of filteredTags | async" [value]="tag">
                    {{ tag }}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
```